# SHL instruction with AND instruction to isolate each bit and jump on carry

Tags: assembly, x86, binary

I am trying display `01011011B AND 11000111b` as an ASCII string of binary digits. I am having real trouble jumping and getting anything to print. I am new at this so any help would be great. Going on 7 hours with minimal progress. Thank you

```
    .stack 100h
    .model small
    .386

    .data

    str1  db  20 dup(?)
    lstring EQU 9

    .code

main: 
    mov ax, @data                ; initialize DS
    mov ds, ax
    mov cx, lstring
L1: 
    mov al,01011011b                     
    and al,11000111b             
    shl al, 1
    loop L1
    mov str1, al
    mov ax, 8
    int 21h

    mov ax, 9                   ;   dos service to display...
    mov bx, 1                   ;   to screen
    mov cx, lstring             ;   number of bytes
    mov dx, OFFSET str1         ;   where to get data
    int 21h

    MOV AH, 4CH                 ; return control to DOS
    INT 21H

end main
```

Answer (score 2):

- Set result to ascii '0'
- Shift test register left once
- Add with carry 0 to result (will still be '0' if carry clear, '1' if set)
- Append that character to the output.
- Repeat 8 times, once per bit.

Edit:
Bear in mind that it's been a great many years since my (brief) dalliance with x86 assembler and I don't have a DOS setup to test it.

```
    mov al,01011011b
    and al,11000111b            ; Only need to do this once
                                ; now al is the intermediate result
    mov cx, 8                   ; Do this 8 times, cx is the loop ctr
    mov bx, OFFSET str1         ; Destination for resulting chars - start at beginning
L1:       ; This is the loop  ; do {
    mov dl, '0'                 ; Ascii character zero
    shl al, 1                   ; Upper bit now in carry flag
    adc dl, 0                   ; Adds carry flag - '0' or '1'
    mov [bx], dl                ; Save ASCII digit to current position
    inc bx                      ; Next position
    loop L1                   ; }while(--cx != 0) ; Counts down cx

    mov byte ptr [bx], '$'      ; Terminate DOS string

    mov ah, 9                   ;   dos service to display $-terminated string
    mov dx, OFFSET str1         ;    where to get data
    int 21h


    MOV AH, 4CH                 ; return control to DOS
    INT 21H
```

DOS system-call documentation: [http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah09](http://spike.scu.edu.au/%7Ebarry/interrupts.html#ah09)

Try that but also learn to use a debugger to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: what do you mean by a string of 01? I don't understand how to shift properly? Are there any good examples of this out there? I am using assembly language for x86 processors 7th edition and its not very helpful to me?

Comment: shl <register> shifts the bits left by one and the top-most bit goes into the carry flag.
adc <register>, 0 adds zero + carry flag to the provided register.
In fact, I've simplifed the response to bypass that and just go straight to the result.

Comment: Can you point out in my code where exactly I would do what your saying. I understand If you don't want to insert the code for me but please point out where in the code You are talking about the carry flag shl. I have the shl I but no matter what I do it either prints a 0 or crashes. thank you for you help.

Comment: I'm trying not to do your homework for you but you want to use shl al, 1 (or whatever register you want to use) to put the top-most bit into the carry flag. Your code won't work because str1 and 2 are *strings* representing binary numbers whereas you want the binary numbers themselves and then store the result in the buffer str3 before passing the offset to str3 in dx to Int 21h setting ax to 9 and not 4000 (in DOS).

Comment: Does this look better this is what I had before but still crashes. I understand you don't want to do my homework and I completely understand. Thank you for the help that you have provided.

Comment: More detailed solution added. It's been a great many years so you'll still have to debug it yourself!

Comment: Mike if your out there thank you. I was able to get everything working. You did need to use a register. I'm having trouble with moving from register to register more so the understanding also the flags.I have been studying this and playing around with this and will continue. Is there a good book out there that you could suggest? Thank you again. I have been working with the debugger just don't understand it yet. I will continue learning though.

Comment: Glad it helped. I originally answered to give you the algorithm, x86 code I would have left to someone who knew much more than I do. Intel's segmented addressing and single-purpose registers were what convinced me that it was time to learn C! What books I have used were more for the specifics of x86 over 6502/68K/IBM370/Z80/Risc but Googling "introduction to x86" seems to bring up plenty of interesting articles.